# After Insert Trigger Oracle - How to ensure only unique record insertion?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I've a question on an after Insert trigger in Oracle 12c.

I have a Dimension table in which DML operations occur via a UI. Whenever there is an Insert or Update, I want to perform Insert or Update in another table, which is called as Rating table.

But the Dimension table is at a lower grain and Rating table is at a higher grain, so I want to insert only unique records in the Rating table.

Is that possible? How?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Existing Trigger Code is as below:-

```
create or replace TRIGGER RFJVBASE.KPI_COCKPIT_ATTR_AFTER_INS2
AFTER INSERT ON RFJVBASE.DIM_KPI_COCKPIT_ATTRS FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_fiscal_week_start varchar2(50);
v_fiscal_week_month_end varchar2(50);
v_fiscal_week_qtr_end varchar2(50);
v_fiscal_week_semi_end varchar2(50);
v_fiscal_week_year_end varchar2(50);
BEGIN
select rfjvbase.run_dates('1-Jan-1900') into v_fiscal_week_start from dual;
select fiscal_month_end_week_name into v_fiscal_week_month_end from rfjvstg.stg_cockpit_business_dt;
select fiscal_qtr_end_week_name into v_fiscal_week_qtr_end from rfjvstg.stg_cockpit_business_dt;
select fiscal_semi_end_week_name into v_fiscal_week_semi_end from rfjvstg.stg_cockpit_business_dt;
select fiscal_year_end_week_name into v_fiscal_week_year_end from rfjvstg.stg_cockpit_business_dt;
/*Insert record into FCT table*/
IF (:new.KPI_TYPE = 'Quantitative') THEN
INSERT INTO RFJVBASE.FCT_KPI_COCKPIT_RATING
    (
PROCESS_KEY_FCT,CURRENT_PROCESS_RATING_KEY,PROCESS_RATING_KEY,CREATED_FISCAL_WEEK,VALID_THROUGH_FISCAL_WEEK,PROCESS_NAME,PROCESS_GROUP,PROCESS,PROCESS_INDICATOR_CLASS,PROCESS_INDICATOR_SEQUENCE,
PERFORMANCE_INDICATOR_NAME,PERF_IND_SUB_LEVEL,UNIT,KPI_TYPE,ORG_UNIT,TOLERANCE_DIRECTION, TOLERANCE,TARGET,TARGET_ENABLE_FLAG,CREATED_DT,CREATED_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DT,LAST_UPDATED_BY,AUDIT_KEY
    )
VALUES
(
FCT_KPI_COCKPIT_RATING_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
:new.PROCESS_KEY,
:new.PROCESS_KEY,
v_fiscal_week_start,
case when :new.ANNUAL_FREQUENCY = 1 then v_fiscal_week_year_end 
     when :new.ANNUAL_FREQUENCY = 2 then v_fiscal_week_semi_end
     when :new.ANNUAL_FREQUENCY = 4 then v_fiscal_week_qtr_end
     when :new.ANNUAL_FREQUENCY = 12 then v_fiscal_week_month_end
end,
:new.PROCESS_NAME,
:new.PROCESS_GROUP,
:new.PROCESS,
:new.PROCESS_INDICATOR_CLASS,
:new.PROCESS_INDICATOR_SEQUENCE,
:new.PERFORMANCE_INDICATOR_NAME,
:new.PERF_IND_SUB_LEVEL,
:new.UNIT,
:new.KPI_TYPE,
:new.ORG_UNIT,
:new.TOLERANCE_DIRECTION,
:new.TOLERANCE,
:new.TARGET,
:new.TARGET_ENABLE_FLAG,
SYSDATE,
:new.USERNAME,
SYSDATE,
:new.USERNAME,
:new.AUDIT_KEY);
ELSE IF (:new.KPI_TYPE = 'Qualitative') THEN
INSERT INTO RFJVBASE.FCT_KPI_COCKPIT_RATING
    (
PROCESS_KEY_FCT,CURRENT_PROCESS_RATING_KEY,PROCESS_RATING_KEY,CREATED_FISCAL_WEEK,VALID_THROUGH_FISCAL_WEEK,PROCESS_NAME,PROCESS_GROUP,PROCESS,PROCESS_INDICATOR_CLASS,PROCESS_INDICATOR_SEQUENCE,
PERFORMANCE_INDICATOR_NAME,PERF_IND_SUB_LEVEL,UNIT,KPI_TYPE,ORG_UNIT,TOLERANCE_DIRECTION, TOLERANCE,TARGET_ENABLE_FLAG,CREATED_DT,CREATED_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DT,LAST_UPDATED_BY,AUDIT_KEY
    )
VALUES
(
FCT_KPI_COCKPIT_RATING_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
:new.PROCESS_KEY,
:new.PROCESS_KEY,
v_fiscal_week_start,
case when :new.ANNUAL_FREQUENCY = 1 then v_fiscal_week_year_end 
     when :new.ANNUAL_FREQUENCY = 2 then v_fiscal_week_semi_end
     when :new.ANNUAL_FREQUENCY = 4 then v_fiscal_week_qtr_end
     when :new.ANNUAL_FREQUENCY = 12 then v_fiscal_week_month_end
end,
:new.PROCESS_NAME,
:new.PROCESS_GROUP,
:new.PROCESS,
:new.PROCESS_INDICATOR_CLASS,
:new.PROCESS_INDICATOR_SEQUENCE,
:new.PERFORMANCE_INDICATOR_NAME,
:new.PERF_IND_SUB_LEVEL,
:new.UNIT,
:new.KPI_TYPE,
:new.ORG_UNIT,
:new.TOLERANCE_DIRECTION,
:new.TOLERANCE,
:new.TARGET_ENABLE_FLAG,
SYSDATE,
:new.USERNAME,
SYSDATE,
:new.USERNAME,
:new.AUDIT_KEY);
END IF;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Perform `select count` and if count is = 0 then insert - otherwise do not insert....

Answer (score 1):

> I want to insert only unique records in the Rating table.

Create **unique index** on the Rating table which won't allow duplicates to be inserted. Let the database do the *dirty* job, you just sit & relax.

Comment: But don't forget to properly handle the exception - otherwise instead of relaxing you would be in big stress  ;-)